# Capybara webkit allow unknown urls is not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using capybara webkit for some of my rspec tests in a rails application. I want to allow_unknown_urls and have set this in the spec_helper.rb file as per the guide for global configuration here https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/  - this is my current spec_helper.rb file:

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
ENV['SERVER_NAME'] = "user.myapp.com"

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rspec/rails"


Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  # Enable debug mode. Prints a log of everything the driver is doing.
  config.debug = false

  config.allow_unknown_urls
  # Allow pages to make requests to any URL without issuing a warning.

  # Allow a specifc domain without issuing a warning.
  config.allow_url("checkout.stripe.com")



  # Timeout if requests take longer than 5 seconds
  config.timeout = 10

  # Don't raise errors when SSL certificates can't be validated
  config.ignore_ssl_errors

end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy= example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.include SignInHelpers, type: :feature
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

As you can see in the webkit configure block I am seting config.allow_unknown_urls and also explicitly allowing checkout.stripe.com

When I run my test which uses the webkit I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.7.
Request to unknown URL: https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/data/languages/en.json
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  page.driver.block_unknown_urls
To allow just this URL:
  page.driver.allow_url("https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/data/languages/en.json")
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  page.driver.allow_url("checkout.stripe.com")
  Buyer creates a new event
```

This confuses me as my webkit has been configured to allow all unknown urls and explicitly checkout.stripe.com. What have I configured incorrectly here?

Comment: What do you get when you check the page.driver state just before that error is raised? It may be that the settings don't get through to your test. E.g. some complex loading might not reload or even use the file where you've set the allowed urls.

Comment: I did an inspect on the page.driver value and this was the output - not sure what I am looking for in here! : http://pastebin.com/G6EQhtzq please let me know if this gives you any useful insight.

Comment: GRepping through that wall-of-data, I see `@options={:allowed_urls=>["*", "checkout.stripe.com"], :block_unknown_urls=>false, :blocked_urls=>[]`, which seems to indicate you have the config in place. However, I see `["*", "checkout.stripe.com"]`. Where does that wildcard come from?

Comment: What do you get when you allow just this url, as per the suggestion `page.driver.allow_url("https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/data/languages/en.json")`. And have you tried to add the https protocol to the host-version: `page.driver.allow_url("https://checkout.stripe.com")`?

Comment: Thewildcard is coming from the config - config.allow_unknown_urls? I have now tried the following config for capybara http://pastebin.com/gUCXS8CU : and this is the output : http://pastebin.com/f5eg6Gww - still getting the same output messages. I am not doing page.driver but I am adding these to the spec_helper.rb config - so that should be equivalent if not better but its not working.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy did you resolve this?

Comment: No :( I didnt sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
config.allow_urls("checkout.stripe.com")
```

The best way to silence the warnings is to block unknown URLs as described in the message: `page.driver.block_unknown_urls`. If your application relies on external resources, APIs, etc., you'll need to permit those URLs via `page.drive.allow_url`. If you don't care about warnings, you can silence them via `page.driver.allow_unknown_hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by removing the 
`js: true`
 from my test.

I think `js: true` specifies a capybara-webkits js driver instead of the default selenium one so if you can get by with the default that may fix this.  (Someone please edit if this is not correct)

That said, I've had a lot of trouble reproducing it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this on one of your `helper` or `env.rb`

```
    $webkit_server = Capybara::Webkit::Server.new 
    $webkit_connection = Capybara::Webkit::Connection.new(server: $webkit_server) 
    $webkit_browser = Capybara::Webkit::Browser.new($webkit_connection) 

    $webkit_browser.allow_unknown_urls

Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
            Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app, :browser => $webkit_browser)
        end
```

Somewhere else I've defined this as well:

`Capybara.default_driver = :webkit`

`Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`

Answer (score 0):

I just had this now. Seems an issue was that I had some empty "placeholder" scenarios in the bottom of my work in progress feature. It was these "empty" scenarios that were causing it for me.

```
Scenario: Write paper
Scenario: Shred paper
Scenario: Realize shredding a mistake
Scenario: Have a good cry
Scenario: Write paper again
```

It seems Capybara::Webkit only invokes the config.allow_url parts when an actual scenario is run. When an empty scenario is present, like here, it will complain about the URL even though it is not being run